# Equivalent to Tkinter's place geometry manager in wxPython

Tags: python, geometry, wxpython

Is there an equivalent to Tkinter's place geometry manager in wxPython?

For those those that don't know, place allows the positioning of widgets based on x y or relative x y coordinates.

I'm a fan of this geometry manager simply because it offers a lot of control over widget positioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best answer is "no, there is no equivalent". You can use absolute positioning with the "pos" keyword argument in the constructor, but that doesn't come close to the power of `place`.

Comment: Just tried it out, it isn't quite the same. However, for my uses it seems like I can make due with it.

Answer (score -1):

The GridBagSizer or FlexGridSizer are kind of like Tkinter's place. Of course, wx also supports absolute positions, although I do not recommend that.

Comment: no, the grid sizers aren't like place at all. They are like grid, though (arguably) harder to use.